# How to carry over information in variable from using a void

Tags: c++

I am a new coder and I am just messing around with functions and testing variables where I got stuck. My goal is to make a function that when you input your name and age it will say "Hello (name) You are (age)" x3 with 3 different names and ages. At the end the program will say "Hello (name1) (name 2) (name 3)" I got everything to work except for the last part and having the names information carry over. How does one do that. (I use C++)

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



void whatisName(string name, int age)
{
    cout << "What is thy name: " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "What is thy age: " << endl;
    cin >> age;

    cout << "Hello " << name << " You are " << age << endl;
}

void allNames(string name1, string name2, string name3 )
{
    cout << "Hello " << name1 << " " << name2 << " " << name3 << " " << endl;
}

int main()
{
string myName, myName2, myName3;
int myage, myage2, myage3;



 whatisName(myName, myage);

 whatisName(myName2, myage2);

 whatisName(myName3, myage3);

 allNames (myName, myName2, myName3);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: When you find yourself sequentially numbering variables, it usually means you want an array. `string myName, myName2, myName3;` could be `string names[3];` and used `whatisName(names[0], ages[0]);`. Then you can put the code into a loop, eg. `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { whatisName(names[i], ages[i]); }`

Answer (score 4):

Pass your variables by reference.

Change:

`void whatisName(string name, int age) { ..`

to:

`void whatisName(string& name, int& age) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

As said above Passing by reference is your best bet. The reason you would want to pass by reference is because your parameter may change after you exit the function. If you don't pass by reference then your parameter will not change when you exit the function

```
    void whatisName(string name, int age){...}
```

this won't change the parameter name or the integer age. So if I put in

```
    string a = "foo";
    int b = 16;
    whatisName(a,b)
```

No matter what happens inside the function a = "foo" and b = 16. Because we haven't created the function to pass by reference. To fix that we go to the function declaration and change it like

```
    whatisName(string &name,int& age)
```

This will now change it so that the parameters inside that function can be modifiable.